# Blur background when focusing on input field with pure JS

Tags: javascript, html

How can I achieve this with pure JS? I am not allowed to use jQuery or a pure CSS solution, so the only way I can think of is pure JavaScript.

I have this demo, for example: **http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jBEMRK**

**HTML:**

```
<body>

   <input type="text">

</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
  background: red;
}

input {
  width: 50%;
}
```

What I want to achieve is that when I click on the input field, I'd love to have the input field focused and the background `(body)` having a backdrop / fade / blur (however it is called). Preferably with a certain opacity, of course.

Comment: You need to post your code in the question - you can't expect users to click away to read your code and try to help

Comment: What JavaScript have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like below. Basically, you can absolutely position a div and then trigger some dim/blur function for that div when the textbox is in focus.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LWEbYG

**HTML**

```
<body>

<input id="txtBox" onfocus="onFocus()" onfocusout="onFocusOut()" type="text">
  <div id="blur"></div> 
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  background: red;
}

input {
  width: 50%;
}
.blury {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.7;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

**JS**

```
function onFocus() {
  document.getElementById('blur').setAttribute('class', 'blury');
}

function onFocusOut() {
  document.getElementById('blur').setAttribute('class', '');
}
```

Comment: Hmm, it seems like it's not blurring the entire screen, hence the left hand side where it's still red. I upvoted you, though.

Comment: Thanks, yet the problem with this one is, is that if you stop focusing on the input field (click somewhere else), the blur stays there... which is not nice.

Comment: You didn't ask for the second part.

Comment: True that, yet I'd expect that that would be the most normal thing to have.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do the following.

HTML part:

```
<input type="text" onblur="blurIt(false)" onfocus="blurIt(true)">
```

JS part:

```
function blurIt(val){
    if (val) document.body.style.background = "black";
    else document.body.style.background = "red";
}
```

Comment: I like it, but I want to use opacity instead of background color. Is that possible too?

Comment: Yes, absolutely! Instead style.background, just go with style.opacity = "0.5", 1.0 being opaque, 0.0 for transparent/invisible.

Comment: Yes, but that blurs everything... including the input field itself. Can we avoid that?

Comment: Sure, it blurs everything because it blurs document.body which is basically everything visible. Instead of document.body, try document.getElementByClassName("allowedToBeBlurred").opacity = "0.5"...
Create a class for it called allowedToBeBlurred, and attach that class to whatever element you want to be blurred.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean **blur** as in **smudge** you could use the webkitfilter property.

### Example:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" onfocus="blurBackground(true)" onblur="blurBackground(false)" />
```

**JS:**

```
function blurBackground(doIt) { 
    if (doIt) document.body.style.webkitFilter = "blur(5px)";
    else document.body.style.webkitFilter = "blur(0)";
}
```

Comment: This one says: "unexpected token do"

Comment: Oops sorry. **do** is a keyword of course (facepalm). Just use a different argument name.

Comment: Have you tried your code? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jBEMRK Look at it... it's blurring the input field but I don't want that. I want it to blur the background of the body, not the input field...

Comment: As asked in my answer. Do you mean blur as in smudge the background (and all its contents except the input field) or do you just want to make it less visible or put a "cloudy" layer over it?

Comment: I want to blur the background and everything else EXCEPT for the input field. So the input field will be emphasized... and when it's not focused on the input field anymore, I want it to go back to normal again.